# Limit in probability of $(\bar X)^2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

Hello can some one point me in the right direction with this question?

Let 
$
  F(x)
= \begin{cases}
  1- x^{-4} & x>1 \\
  0       & elsewhere \\
  \end{cases}
$ 
be the CDF of a random variable $X$

a) Find the limit in probability of $(\bar X_n)^2$ where $\bar X_n$ is a sample mean of a sample of size $n$ from $F$. Justify your steps.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the expectation and variance for $X$.  Verify that the variance is finite.  Apply the central limit theorem for sample sums.